# pragma omp parallel for vs. pragma omp parallel

Tags: c++, openmp

In C++ with openMP, is there any difference between

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
   ...
}
```

and

```
#pragma omp parallel
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
   ...
}
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: The second case has each thread to the same job (the entire for loop). The first case shares the work between threads so each thread does `N/t` iterations where `t` is the number of threads.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#pragma omp parallel
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
   ...
}
```

This code creates a parallel region, and each individual thread executes what is in your loop. In other words, you do the complete loop N times, instead of N threads splitting up the loop and completing all iterations just once.

You can do:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for( int i=0; i < N; ++i )
    {
    }

    #pragma omp for
    for( int i=0; i < N; ++i )
    {
    }
}
```

This will create one parallel region (aka one fork/join, which is expensive and therefore you don't want to do it for every loop) and run multiple loops in parallel within that region. Just make sure if you already have a parallel region you use `#pragma omp for` as opposed to `#pragma omp parrallel for` as the latter will mean that each of your N threads spawns N more threads to do the loop.

Comment: I see; that's what I needed. So the first option (`#pragma omp parallel`) would execute Nthreads * N iterations in total, and any statement of the form `vec[i] = result;` inside the loop would mess everything up.

Comment: @FranciscoJ.R.Ruiz that's correct. If this answer's your question, feel free to mark it as the answer  :)

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot.