# Should I use braces if I want to use openmp critical before a loop?

Tags: c++, openmp

Is it enough to write  :

```
#pragma omp critical
for (...) {
    ...
}
```

Or must I write :

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    for (...) {
        ...
        }
}
```

Comment: May be this link will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080818/pragma-omp-parallel-for-vs-pragma-omp-parallel

Answer (score 3):

The target of the `critical` construct is the statement immediately following it. From that point of view, `for (...) { ... }` is a single statement, therefore the braces are not strictly required. This also applies to other constructs such as `parallel`, `for`, combined `parallel for`, `atomic`, etc.