# Difference between #pragma omp parallel and #pragma omp parallel for

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am new to `OpenMP` and I have been trying to run a program which adds two arrays using OpenMP. In the OpenMP tutorial, I have learned that we need to use **#pragma omp parallel for** while using OpenMP on the *for* loop. But I have also tried the same thing with **#pragma omp parallel** and it is also giving me the correct output. Below are the code snippets of what I am trying to convey.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
{
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {  
            c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
       }
}
```

and

```
 #pragma omp parallel
{
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {  
            c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
       }
}
```

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pragma omp parallel for vs. pragma omp parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080818/pragma-omp-parallel-for-vs-pragma-omp-parallel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The

`#pragma omp parallel`:

will create a `parallel region` with a team of `threads`, where each thread will execute the entire block of code that the `parallel region` encloses.

From the [OpenMP 5.1](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf) one can read a more formal description :

> When a thread encounters a **parallel construct**, **a team of threads is
> created** to execute the parallel region (..). The
> thread that encountered the parallel construct becomes the primary
> thread of the new team, with a thread number of zero for the duration
> of the new parallel region. **All threads in the new team, including the
> primary thread, execute the region.** Once the team is created, the
> number of threads in the team remains constant for the duration of
> that parallel region.

The:

`#pragma omp parallel for`

will create a `parallel region` (as described before), and to the `threads` of that region the iterations of the loop that it encloses will be assigned, using the `default chunk size`, and the `default schedule` which is *typically* `static`. Bear in mind, however, that the `default schedule` might differ among different concrete implementation of the `OpenMP` standard.

From the [OpenMP 5.1](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf) you can read a more formal description :

> The worksharing-loop construct specifies that the iterations of one or
> more associated loops will be executed in parallel by threads in the
> team in the context of their implicit tasks. **The iterations are
> distributed across threads that already exist in the team that is
> executing the parallel region to which the worksharing-loop region
> binds**.

[Moreover](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf),

> The parallel loop construct is a shortcut for specifying a parallel
> construct containing a loop construct with one or more associated
> loops and no other statements.

Or informally, `#pragma omp parallel for` is a combination of the constructor `#pragma omp parallel` with `#pragma omp for`. In your case, this would mean that:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
{
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {  
            c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
       }
}
```

is semantically, and logically, the same as:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
      #pragma omp for
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {  
            c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
       }
}
```

**TL;DR:** In your example, with `#pragma omp parallel for` the loop will be parallelized among threads (*i.e.,* the loop iterations will be divided among threads), whereas with `#pragma omp parallel` **all** threads will execute (in parallel) **all** the loop iterations.

To make it more illustrative, with `4` threads the `#pragma omp parallel`, would result in something like:

[image]

whereas `#pragma omp parallel for` with a `chunk_size=1` and a *static* `schedule` would result in something like:

[image]

Code-wise the loop would be transformed to something *logically* similar to:

```
for(int i=omp_get_thread_num(); i < n; i+=omp_get_num_threads())
{  
    c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
}
```

where [omp_get_thread_num()](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu113.html)

> The omp_get_thread_num routine returns the thread number, within the
> current team, of the calling thread.

and [omp_get_num_threads()](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu113.html)

> Returns the number of threads in the current team. In a sequential
> section of the program omp_get_num_threads returns 1.

or in other words, `for(int i = THREAD_ID; i < n; i += TOTAL_THREADS)`. With `THREAD_ID` ranging from `0` to `TOTAL_THREADS - 1`, and `TOTAL_THREADS` representing the total number of threads of the team created on the parallel region.

> I have learned that we need to use #pragma omp parallel for while
> using OpenMP on the for loop. **But I have also tried the same thing
> with #pragma omp parallel and it is also giving me the correct output.**

It gives you the same output, because in your code:

```
 c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
```

array `a` and array `b` are only read, and array `c[i]` is the only one being updated, and its value does not depend on how many times the iteration `i` will be executed. Nevertheless, with `#pragma omp parallel for` each thread will update its own `i`,  whereas with `#pragma omp parallel` threads will be updating the same `i`s, hence overriding each others values.

Now try to do the same with the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
{
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {  
            c[i]= c[i] + a[i] + b[i];
       }
}
```

and

```
#pragma omp for
{
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {  
            c[i] = c[i] + a[i] + b[i];
       }
}
```

you will immediately notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, the loop is not parallelized. Namely, the **whole loop is executed in each thread**. Generally, whatever is inside the parallel region is executed by all the threads.

You can additionally parallelize the loop in the already existing parallel region as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp for
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```