# Didn't understand the output from parallel reduction using max operation OpenMP program?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I was reading about parallel programming and came across this basic code.
This is the program from parallel reduction using max operation. What exactly we are expecting from this operation?

```
 
 #include <stdio.h>

 #include <omp.h>

 int main() {
   double arr[10];
   omp_set_num_threads(4);
   double max_val = 0.0;
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     arr[i] = 2.0 + i;
   #pragma omp parallel
   for reduction(max: max_val)
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     printf("thread id = %d  and i = %d \n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
     if (arr[i] > max_val) {
       max_val = arr[i];
     }
   }
   printf("\nmax_val = %f", max_val);
 }
```

and this is the output

```
thread id = 2  and i = 6
thread id = 2  and i = 7
thread id = 1  and i = 3
thread id = 1  and i = 4
thread id = 1  and i = 5
thread id = 3  and i = 8
thread id = 3  and i = 9
thread id = 0  and i = 0
thread id = 0  and i = 1
thread id = 0  and i = 2

max_val = 11.000000
```

I am new to openmp. Please help me to understand this code. I am not getting this output. How this result came?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fills up the `arr`:

```
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     arr[i] = 2.0 + i;
```

with values from `2 to 11`:

then in the parallel loop:

```
   #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max: max_val)
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     printf("thread id = %d  and i = %d \n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
     if (arr[i] > max_val) {
       max_val = arr[i];
     }
   }
```

When OpenMP *reads* `#pragma omp parallel for` OpenMP will divide the iterations of the loop among a team to threads, in your case 4 threads:

```
 omp_set_num_threads(4);
```

A more detailed answer about `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp parallel for` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65247845/1366871).

With `reduction(max: max_val)` OpenMP will create a copy of the variable `max_val` *per* thread and after the parallel region the original variable `max_val` will be equals to the biggest `max_val` among all threads. Which in your case is `11.0`.

A more detailed answer about the reduction clause can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65406679/1366871).

The function `omp_get_thread_num()` returns back the ID of the thread that have invoked that method.