# Why "#pragma omp parallel {#pragma omp parallel for}" differs from "#pragma omp parallel" in execution times?

Tags: for-loop, openmp

**Based on：[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247801/difference-between-pragma-omp-parallel-and-pragma-omp-parallel-for)**

**Known:** number of processors: **28**

> Code 1:
>
> ```
> void fun1()
> {
>     printf("Hello, world\n");
> }
> #pragma omp parallel
> {
>     fun1();
> }
> ```
>
> Code 2:
>
> ```
> void fun2()
> {
>     #pragma omp for
>     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
>     {
>         printf("Hello, world\n");
>     }
> }
> #pragma omp parallel
> {
>     fun2();
> }
> ```
>
> Code 3:
>
> ```
> #pragma omp parallel
> {
>     #pragma omp for
>     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
>     {
>         printf("Hello, world\n");
>     }
> }
> ```

> **Results:**
>
> Code1: printf is executed 28*1=28 times.
>
> Code2 is equivalent to Code3: printf is executed 10 times. **WHY？WHY NOT
> printf is executed 28*10=280 times, with each of the 28 threads
> responsible for the whole for-loop?**

---

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

**Question:**

> Why
>
> ```
> #pragma omp parallel
> {
>     #pragma omp for
>     for(int i=0;i<N;i++){}
> }
> ```
>
> results in that every iteration of the loop is executed 1 time, and why not
>
> ```
> #pragma omp for
> for(int i=0;i<N;i++){}
> ```
>
> (i.e. code within { } above) executed as many times as the numbers of threads(denoted as M)
> according to the specifications of "#pragma omp parallel", namely
> every iteration of the loop is respectively executed M times by M
> threads?

> or maybe this kind of nested parallel construct by "for" can't be
> natively explained by the specifications of "#pragma omp parallel"
> because of implementations ?

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. There is no parallel region (`#pragma omp parallel`) in your second code. Without a parallel region `#pragma omp for` has no effect at all.

Comment: I have made some changes in my description. The second code snippet is exactly the lines enclosed by outer {} in the first snippet. @Laci

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
#pragma omp for
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){}
```

is practically sequential code.  As per the section [Worksharing-Loop Construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu48.html#x73-730002.11.4) in the OpenMP specification, the `for` construct needs a `parallel` construct that it binds to.  The `parallel` construct creates the threads that the `for` uses to execute in parallel.  So, you indeed have to write

```
#pragma omp parallel  // creates the threads
{
    #pragma omp for   // execute in parallel
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){}
}
```

You can use the shorter form, too:

```
#pragma omp parallel for   // create threads & execute in parallel
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){}
```

**UPDATE** (to reflect the update to the original post):

Code 1 in the original post runs 28 threads in the parallel region, each calling the function, and printing "Hello World".

Code 2 and code 3 spawn 28 threads.  Code 2 calls the function and the `for` construct distributes 10 loop iterations across 28 threads.  Since there are only 10 iterations, only 10 invocations of `printf` will happen, and only 10 threads will actively print.  The other 18 will do nothing.  Same for Code 3.

The link I have provided explains what the `for` construct does.

Comment: I have adjusted my question description to make it clear. The code "#pragma omp for
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){}" is not a independent code. I mean it's a whole, which is enclosed by "#pragma omp parallel{ }"

Answer (score 0):

The two basic concepts in OpenMP are 1. the parallel region: if you encounter `omp parallel` a *team* of threads is created, and each thread starts executing the region. And 2. "worksharing constructs", of which `omp for` is the most obvious one. If you have a team of threads, the work is distributed over those threads. So in both your codes 2 & 3 you create a team, and then the team encounters the loop and distributes the iterations.

You are wondering why not every thread executes the whole loop? That would happen if you omit the `omp for`. In that case the loop is an instruction like any other, and each thread executes it in its entirety.